# netty test: how to send a post to handler

Tags: java, http, post, netty

I want to test a ChannelInboundHandler in Netty, It's input is `HTTPFullRequest`.

Here is my post:

```
POST  HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
paramA=dataA\
&paramB=dataB
```

I use EmbbedChannel to test the handler, here is the code.

```
EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(
        new ChannelInitializer<EmbeddedChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(EmbeddedChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                p.addLast("httpCodec", new HttpServerCodec());
                p.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(100000));
                p.addLast("readPost", new ReadPost());

            }
        }
    );
// input contains the post above.
assertTrue((channel.writeInbound(input.retain())));
```

but my `ReadPost` always read a bad post complaining `failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text is empty (possibly HTTP/0.9))`

And here is my ReadPost handler snapshot:

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    if (msg instanceof FullHttpRequest) {
        FullHttpRequest req = (FullHttpRequest) msg;
        if (req.method().equals(HttpMethod.POST)) {
            .....
        }
```

anyone know why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

emmm .

It is simply the fault of http syntax.

`POST  HTTP/1.1` needs host name, the right syntax is like `POST / HTTP/1.1`.

the http header also lacks a `Content-Length`.

yes, that's all .

I am so stupid.